# Mathematics - velocity & acceleration

Tags: classical-mechanics, word-problem

A scooter accelerates from rest 100m before the traffic lights at a constant rate of $1.5m/s^2$ until it reaches 6m/s. It then travels at this speed until it reaches a point 50m beyond the traffic lights. At that point the scooter starts to slow at a constant rate of $1m/s^2$ until it stops.

Sketch the displacement time graph

The first part would be $u=0, s=-100m, a=1.5m/s^2, v=6m/s. a=v-u/t$, so $t= 4s, s= -100+12= -88m$. When $t= 4s, s= -88m$

I am not getting the value of time for $50m$.

Comment: The first part would be u=0, s=-100m, a=1.5m/s^2, v=6m/s. a=v-u/t, so t= 4s, s= -100+12= -88m. When t= 4s, s= -88m

Comment: Iam not getting the value of time for 50m.